# JQuery Autocomplete — как сделать так, чтобы в выпадающем списке первой была строка, начинающаяся на введенную последовательность?

Tags: jquery

JQuery Autocomplete - как сделать так, чтобы в выпадающем списке первой была строка, начинающаяся на введенную последовательность?

Вот, например, если пройти на их сайт:
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
и ввести в поле "Tags" букву j.
Выпадет список:
Clojure
Java
Javascript

Но ведь я ввел j. Почему первым выпадает Clojure? Как сделать, чтобы Java? Она ведь на J начинается.

Answer (score 1):

В каком порядке подадите - в таком и покажет.

```js
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript",
  "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"
];
$("#tags").autocomplete({
  source: function(rqst, callback) {
    var term = rqst.term.toLowerCase();
    var terms = availableTags.filter(function(item){
      return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) != -1;
    });
    terms.sort(function(a, b){
      a = a.toLowerCase();
      b = b.toLowerCase();
      var indexA = a.indexOf(term);
      if (indexA == -1)
        indexA = 1000;
      var indexB = b.indexOf(term);
      if (indexB == -1)
        indexB = 1000;
      if (indexA > indexB)
        return 1;
      if (indexB > indexA)
        return -1;
      if (a > b)
        return 1;
      if (a < b)
        return -1;
      return 0;
    });
    callback(terms);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```